# Modify Matching Objects using Java Streams

Tags: java, stream

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
class Person {
  public String name;
  public double netWorth;
  public Person(String name, String netWorth) { this.name = name; this.netWorth = netWorth; }
}
```

and following stream:

```
Stream.of(
  new Person("Jeff Bezos", 12),
  new Person("Jeff Bezos", 165_345_678_910), 
  new Person("Jeff Bezos", 1_234),
  new Person("Jeff Bezos(1)", 1_234),
  new Person("Jeff Bezos(1)(2)", 42),
  new Person("Bill Gates", 130_000_000_000));
```

by using Java Streams API I want to transform stream above so that:

- `Person`-s with same names should receive different strings (by adding `(i)`) in the end of the name
- no cycles /  if statements / interim stream terminators
- order of names does not matter, e.g. out of two `Person`-s with same names either of two can receive `(1)` suffix

e.g. to a following map:

```
new HashMap<String, Double>() {{
  put("Jeff Bezos", 12);
  put("Jeff Bezos(1)(1)(1)", 165_345_678_91);
  put("Jeff Bezos(1)(1)(2)", 1_234);
  put("Jeff Bezos(1)", 1_234);
  put("Jeff Bezos(1)(2)", 42);
  put("Bill Gates", 130_000_000_000);
}};
```

P.S. Complicatoion, order of `Person`s matter, person with the highest net worth should receive the cleanest name, e.g. with min suffixes etc:

```
new HashMap<String, Double>() {{
  put("Jeff Bezos", 165_345_678_91);
  put("Jeff Bezos(1)(1)(1)", 1_234);
  put("Jeff Bezos(1)(1)(2)", 12);
  put("Jeff Bezos(1)(2)", 42);
  put("Jeff Bezos(1)", 1_234);
  put("Bill Gates", 130_000_000_000);
}};
```

Comment: @levgen has never accepted an answer.

Comment: Did you have an **attempt**, what are the problems you've encountered? You've listed only requirements and sample data.